# ¿Por qué al hacer "git branch -a" no me salen unas ramas que sé que existen?

Tags: git, ramas-git

Estoy tratando de colaborar en un repositorio de gitlab, así que hice un `git clone`, en principio me daba error, así que lo hice con este comando:

```
git clone http://gitlab.com/large-repository --depth 1
```

y funcionó.

Luego estaba intentando ver las ramas con `git checkout` y me daba error, me moví al directorio donde había clonado el repositorio e hice `git init` , luego volví a ejecutar 'git checkout' y lo que hace es devolverme (master) así entre paréntesis, pero en el repositorio hay 2 ramas mas aparte de master y aquí no me aparecen.

Intenté el comando `git branch -a` y me devuelve lo mismo.

Por último probé `git fetch` y no hace nada, no muestra error pero tampoco se ve que haga algo.

NOTA: me di cuenta de que no estaba dentro de la carpeta que me creó al clonar el repositorio. ;e cambié a este carpeta, ejecuté `git branch -a` y me lista estas 3 ramas:

- * master
- remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
- remotes/origin/master

pero en el git lab, hay 3 ramas que son:

- master
- develop1
- develop2

Esas dos últimas no me aparecen, y si ejecuto 'git checkout develop1' me muestra este error:

> error: pathspec 'jd' did not match any file(s) known to git .

Comment: Buenas, quizás por leer rápido o no prestar atención no entiendo el problema que tienes ¿Deseas cambiar de ramas, colaborar en un proyecto y desear copiarlo a local o quieres una explicación básica de git? ¿Cuales son tus dudas?

Comment: Si te ves desorientando con los comandos git , puedes intentar utilizar una version GUI para familiarizarte mejor con el mundo de Git y una vez entiendas como funciona volver a la consola

Comment: @ICodeForCaffeine Gracias por responder. lo que intento es colaborar en un proyecto. lo cloné y estoy teniendo todo esos problemas, el principal es que no me aparecen las ramas que aparecen en gitlab, acabo de agregar una nota a mi pregunta, ya que me había dado cuenta de que no estaba ejecutando los comandos dentro de la carpeta del proyecto que se creó al clonarlo.

Comment: git fetch es para sincronizar lo que hay en el servidor con lo que hay en tu equipo.  si cuando hiciste ese fetch no estaban las ramas develop1 y develop2,seguiras sin verlas. Prueba otra vez con git fetch a ver si te sincroniza y aparecen origin/develop1 y origin/develop2

Comment: ¿Y si haces `git clone` a secas, sin el depth?

Comment: @Jakala hice el git fetch y luego cuando hago el git branch -a me lista estas 3 ramas: master,  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master y remotes/origin/master . Encontré este comando: git ls-remote y me muestra esto: 56e8c4ee30cf156ae4490e4353d6cd09f0cbc560        HEAD
56e8c4ee30cf156ae4490e4353d6cd09f0cbc560        refs/heads/develop2
56e8c4ee30cf156ae4490e4353d6cd09f0cbc560        refs/heads/master
0cc4b5cf87c85f6a7da34337af59c50fa98e084a        refs/heads/develop1 . No entiendo que significa eso.

Comment: @fedorqui con ese no se me terminaba de descargar el repositorio, leí que para conecciones lentas usara ese depth.

Comment: Por el error que has indicado creo que tienes la referencia al origin/master corrompido, quizás tengas que hacer un borrado con **rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/master** o borrar el repositorio completo y volver a clonarlo.

Comment: Amigo de verdad no entiendo que pasa, borre la carpeta que me creo al clonar el repositorio, volvi a ejecutar git clone link-repositorio y me muestra estos errores: Cloning into 'wcom'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 1239, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1239/1239), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (926/926), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed , por lo que tengo que hacerlo con git clone linkrepositorio depth 1 , eso tendrá algo q ver?

Comment: No se que paso, el git init lo había ejecutado fuera de la carpeta del repositorio clonado, lo que hice fue eliminar la carpeta .init. volví a ejecutar git clone (sin el depth 1) y esta vez si funcionó, me moví a la carpeta y ahora si me aparecen las ramas. si deseo crear una rama esta se crea en local, correcto? como haría para que se cree también en el repositorio remoto ?

Comment: Prueba con la respuesta que te han dado, volver a clonar (sin el depth ya que creo que no te permitirá hacer fetch), comprobarlo con el checkout y a ver que ocurre. También recomiendo lo que ha indicado Capt. de usar algun programa que te permita tener una GUI, te recomiendo Gitkraken o SourceTree. Editado: Para lo de las ramas en remoto echa un vistazo en https://vabadus.es/blog/otros/git-trabajando-con-ramas-remotas , espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 4):

No te aparecen las ramas porque hiciste `git init` donde ya tenías un repositorio (el que habías clonado). Y éste comando (`git init`) lo que hace es que te crea un repo desde cero (por lo que supongo que te haya borrado el que tenías).

Lo que te sugiero es que vuelvas a clonar con:

```
git clone http://gitlab.com/large-repository
```

Y luego vuelve a comprobar con:

```
git checkout
```

o con:

```
git branch -a
```

Recuerda ejecutar estos dos últimos comandos en la raíz de la carpeta donde tengas el repo clonado (o sea dentro de la carpeta que contiene un directorio `.git` oculto)

Comment: cuáles serían los pasos, borro la carpeta que se me creó al clonar el repositorio y vuelvo a ejecutar el git clone ?

Comment: Si, empieza desde cero como te puse en la respuesta. Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Hola @AdrianaHernández, disculpa pero tu te pareces mucho a una muchacha que estudio conmigo en la universidad, eres de cuba?

Comment: @Japv Sí, soy de Cuba, así que probablemente sea yo. Escríbeme al mail para saber quien eres tu. adriana.hregueiro@gmail.com Saludo!

Answer (score 1):

Aunque no te aparezca el branch deseado, utiliza el siguiente comando:

```
git branch nombreBranch
```

de esta manera aparecerá el branch y ya lo podrás utilizar:

```
git checkout nombreBranch
```

Saludos!